# Target children of multiple classes with one CSS selector rule

Tags: html, css

Let's assume that I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div>
      <div class="class1">
          <p class="subclass">whatever</p>
      </div>
      <div class="class2">
          <p class="subclass">whatever</p>
      </div>
      <div class="class3">
          <p class="subclass">whatever</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to have one CSS selector rule to target the elements with the class name `subclass` under ancestors with classnames `class1` or `class2` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the attribute selector with `:not()` to select anything that starts with `.class*` and exclude `.class3`

```css
[class^="class"]:not(.class3) .subclass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
      <div class="class1">
          <p class="subclass">whatever</p>
      </div>
      <div class="class2">
          <p class="subclass">whatever</p>
      </div>
      <div class="class3">
          <p class="subclass">whatever</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

You can always combine selectors

```css
.class1 .subclass, .class2 .subclass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
      <div class="class1">
          <p class="subclass">whatever</p>
      </div>
      <div class="class2">
          <p class="subclass">whatever</p>
      </div>
      <div class="class3">
          <p class="subclass">whatever</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For few items, I would go with option 2, with many items same rule I will go with option 1. 
Option 2 is more readable and modifiable with less complexity. 
Thank you for your clear answer.